# Windows and Ubuntu Linking

Tags: networking, compiling, dynamic-linking

I am a PhD student doing Aeroelastic CFD simulations and I am working with one fluid open source code (Flower) running on Ubuntu and one commercial sturctural csoftware (SIMPACK) running on Windows and I want to pass the output from one code to the other in two diriction. can anybody help me to do this link?

Mohamed

Answer (score 1):

I think your question should be more appropriate in StackOverFlow but to answer shortly:

you could achieve that using network to communicate the output of a program to another one or you can use a shared folder that you output the result of one program and the other one grab that output, assuming you're running applications in a virtual machine for each one.

Another way is to run Flower on Windows also since it says it is compatible to run on Windows according to that site: http://sourceforge.net/projects/openflower/

Answer (score 0):

It seems you want to transfer files between your computers. The easiest way to do that is to... use USB stick. Windows and Linux both support either FAT or NTFS as filesystems.

Alternatively, share folder using Samba (on Ubuntu) or with standard Windows filesharing on your Windows PC (right-click on the folder in Explorer and select "Share").

It might be a good idea to not to use files directly from the network share (and instead copy those to your local computer), as random access over network is relatively slow compared to local files.